# A very odd issue with std::fclose()

Tags: c++, file

I was doing some simple read/write operations on files using MS Visual Studio. Here is a simplified version of the code I wrote:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void write_into_file(const char* filename);

int main()
{
    write_into_file("settings.ini");
    write_into_file("com4.ini");
    return 0;
}

void write_into_file(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* f = std::fopen(filename, "wb");
    const char* text = "Some text I want to write...";
    std::fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), f);
    std::fclose(f);
}
```

Whenever I run the program, it gets stuck and does not end. I debugged the code and traced into it. Turned out that all parts of the code are okay and run without any problems, except the line that contains `fclose`. I mean, the debugger gets stuck when it reaches that line. Why this happens and what is the problem?

**EDIT :** 
 I suspected that the problem is with the name of files, specially `com4.ini`. So I changed the code as follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void write_into_file(const char* filename)
{
    std::ofstream fp(filename, std::ios::out);
    if (fp.is_open())
        fp.close();
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(filename, &info) != 0)
    {
        perror("An error occurred. Write permissions maybe?!!");
        return;
    }
    FILE* f = std::fopen(filename, "wb");
    const char* text = "Some text I want to write...";
    std::fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), f);
    std::fclose(f);
}
```

The funny thing is, it writes the first file successfully. For the second file, it passes the existence check and again, gets stuck at the last line. It doesn't even throw an exception! Just remains there doing nothing...

Comment: This looks like a permissions or access problem to me (but I'm just speculating). Can you create the files manually? (if it's a permission problem, you will not be able to). Also, if you add a std::fflush call before the std::fclose, your application will get stuck in the fflush call instead. If this is the case, the solutions would be to (1) fix the permissions at OS level or (2) explicitly set current working directory in your application or (3) explicitly set the path for the files, to somewhere you have write access.

Comment: It has nothing with this issue, but you have to use `std::strlen` instead `strlen`.

Comment: ... or change to std::string and use it's size

Comment: Please see the edited part of the question

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I definitely believe that's not the problem

Comment: Does it happen with the simplified version?

Comment: @n.m. Yes it does :o

Comment: I'm asking because things like this sometimes happen when a buffer overflow occurs. But I don't see any buffer overflow in the posted code. The only problem is not checking the return value of fopen.

Comment: I added a watch for `f` and it wasn't `NULL` after `fopen` @n.m.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx



CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces.

Comment: where did I say that's the problem. I just continue with a suggestion along with ikh's comment

Answer (score 4):

You can't use COM4.ini as a filename,  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx
Specifially

"CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces."

It attempts to open a serial port called COM4 instead...

Comment: So how can I check for such names without getting stuck?

Comment: @polfosol Probably the simplest way is to compare the name part (before the dot and after the last directory separator or drive letter, if any) with the given list of reserved names.

Comment: Alternatively, you could allow such reserved filenames as they are valid filenames anyway. If you specify "com4.ini", the system assumes you really mean what you say, i.e. you want to write to the COM port. In some cases, it's a valid thing to do. In your case, it's not, so don't name it like that to begin with, without having to write a "nanny" function to prevent you doing that.